# Using Mercurial with Perforce

Tags: mercurial, interop, perforce, dvcs

Does anybody have any advice about using Mercurial as a front end for Perforce?  What I would like to do is to use Mercurial to handle really granular changes and then, once I'm done something, push it back up to the Perforce server.

I found this article http://www.dehora.net/journal/2008/01/05/using-mercurial-with-perforce/ but it doesn't suggest any tooling to help out with the integrations.  Does any exist?  I suppose I am looking for it pull any new changes from Perforce, integrate them into my local Mercurial then roll up all the Mercurial commits I've made since last integration and push them up to Perforce.  Similar to git-p4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an error when I followed the link you gave. But I suggest you look into the [perfarce extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PerfarceExtension) (I love the name!). I have not used it myself, but it's my understanding that this is what people use to bridge the gap between Mercurial and Perforce.

See also the wiki page on [Perforce concepts](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PerforceConcepts). It seems to have a lot of good info.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin says, [Perfarce](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PerfarceExtension) is what you want. I've used it at a previous job, and in general it works pretty well if you're just working with a single perforce branch into a single mercurial clone. If you start cloning multiple times from your original Mercurial clone, then things start getting complex. Not impossible, just complex.

In general it works by bundling all changes since you last pulled from Perforce. Creating a single perforce changelist from them. Tagging that changelist's comment with the hash of the Mercurial version and committing it to perforce. It then re-imports that change from Perforce and merges it into your Mercurial tree, and because they're both the same there's no merge.

Basically it works quite well for pull/edit/commit/update workflows. Unfortunately it's not any help when it comes to integrations (unless I missed something) as perforce branches aren't converted to Mercurial ones. It wouldn't know what to merge.